# How does tf.control_dependencies work for operations defined elsewhere?

Tags: tensorflow

In the newest tensorflow code, the line (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/training/python/training/training.py#L428) intends to make sure that `total_loss` is computed after finishing `update_ops`.

However, my question is that the `total_loss` is defined elsewhere. There is just a reference to `total_loss`, which should not make the `control_dependencies` effective.

How does it ensure that `total_loss` are computed after finishing `update_ops`? I mean the `total_loss` might be computed with stale values of variables before `update_ops`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indeed won't affect the originally defined op (running that won't trigger update ops), but the new op (confusingly also referred to by the Python variable `total_loss`) returned by [`with_dependencies`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1897cea1807c28d998b7efc3906de48d75d99a6d/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py#L3254) has control dependencies on the update ops and so will only run once they've run. The new op with control dependencies [is passed as the loss to `compute_gradients`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1897cea1807c28d998b7efc3906de48d75d99a6d/tensorflow/contrib/training/python/training/training.py#L443) and so gets tied into the train op.

Comment: Thank you for your answer:-). But it does not solve my problem. I know the new total_loss gets tied into the update_ops. But the old total_loss does not. So how do we ensure the old total_loss is computed with the variables after update_ops?

Comment: Ah, a seeming race condition, good question. When I see "update ops" I think "batch norm", which is pretty much the only update op in common use. Batch norm's updates do not affect loss values during training (batch statistics are used) so it doesn't matter when the update happens. In general I'd expect this to be the case: updates which would be racy if done in parallel would use a different mechanism (e.g. add control dependencies to a variable read).